# Why is this sentence grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses

> Albert Einstein, who will always be revered in history, was not only a great scientist but a great human being.

What's wrong with that sentence? My teacher gave us a hint and said the problem may be with the verbs and tenses.

He did say the following sentence is right:

> Albert Einstein, who was not only a great scientist but a great human being, will always be revered in history.

Is it ok to use future tense in relative clause? I mean the relative clause is supposed to describe the antecedent so will there be any problem if we use future tense in relative clause?

Comment: Have you copied the sentence exactly? Including the punctuation marks, spaces, and capital letters. Please explain "where" you think the error(s) lie.

Comment: Well our teacher gave us a hint.and said the problem may be with the verbs and tenses

Comment: 'Albert Einstein, who will always be revered in _science_ ...

Comment: Did your teacher write *einstein* with a lower-case letter? That is  *one* important orthographic (not grammar) error. Frankly, apart from the spacing (there should be no space before a comma) I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: No he just said the sentence so  plz don't pay attention to those problems

Comment: I almost want to downvote your post after reading your comments on Andrew Leach's answer. There are many ways of rewriting that sentence, you asked why it was grammatically wrong, nothing about how it could be reworded or improved. See Edwin's suggestion.

Comment: Conclusion: the sentence _isn’t_ grammatically wrong. If your teacher says it is, it’s your teacher who is wrong. There is nothing wrong with future tenses in relative clauses. _Stylistically_, there are better ways to phrase the sentence, but style is not grammar. You can always improve on how you word something; that's why it takes good writers so long to write their books, while Dan Brown spits out five books a year.

Answer (score 5):

If we remove the parenthetical insertion we get

> Albert Einstein was not only a great scientist but a great human being.

That's fine. He lived in the past so the use of *was* is correct. You could add *too* or *as well* on the end, but it's not necessary.

So if there is an error, it must be in the "who will always be revered in history".

This might be considered odd because it refers to history with the future tense, "**will be** revered." History is not in the future; it is only in the past. You can't have something that *will happen* in history (apart from some specialist uses of the present historic). Something that *will happen* will always be in the future.

If we replace *history* with *the future*, we get

> Albert Einstein, who will always be revered in the future, was not only a great scientist but a great human being.

This makes more sense temporally, but it's now tautologous because you don't need *will be* **and** "in the future" together. That's bad style rather than bad grammar.

However, I think this may be being too strict. "In history" could be understood to mean "as a historical figure". And if that's the case, then the sentence makes perfect sense because he will always be a historical figure.

> Albert Einstein, who will always be revered as a historical figure, was not only a great scientist but a great human being.

English is not an exact science. While there are rules, even those come from usage. I don't believe many would perceive "will be revered in history" as particularly odd.

---

And to answer the last part of the question, added later, "Is it ok to use the future tense in a relative clause? I mean the relative clause is supposed to describe the antecedent so will there be any problem if we use the future tense in a relative clause?"

It's fine. Consider

> This motorway, which will carry traffic for the next fifty years, was completed today with the generous help of Sunnyvale Funeral Home.
>
> This motorway, which was completed today, will carry traffic for the next fifty years.

The sentences are identical. The order in which the clauses appear influences how important they are: a parenthetical insertion is less noteworthy simply because it is an omissible addition. In the first example here, the audience might know of the lifespan but not the generous donation; in the second, the audience knows the motorway was completed but might be impressed with its planned longevity.

Comment: What a relief to find there is nothing "wrong" with that sentence. Surely *history* in that context means for "all time", could someone be so nitpicky about that?

Comment: So is that the problem? If yes why did he say that the following sentence is right? Albert Enstein,who was not only a great scientist but a great human being,will always be revealed in history.

Comment: *Revealed* or *revered*? I think I've answered that, anyway. I don't think the two sentences are any different. But if you have additional information like that then you should have included it in your question at the outset.

Comment: Is it ok to use future tense in relative clause? I mean the relative clause is supposed to describe the antecedent so will be any problem if we use future tense in relative clause?

Comment: Revered sorry about the mistake

Comment: @solmazpanaahi ***Please add all of this to the question.*** Do not bury relevant information in comments, and particularly not comments on answers.

Comment: I certainly don't find _will be revered in history_ odd because of _history_ being past—a good parallel is the set phrase _will go down in history_. History is inherently past, but with a future tense verb, it's just the past as seen from that future point in time. Still, I find it a bit odd to collocate _revere_ with the prepositional phrase _in history_. I'd say something like “who will always be revered as a great historical figure” instead. But that too is a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I agree. My use of *This is odd* is overstating it (and I argue against it myself!) Perhaps that should be "This might be considered odd".